# Route 53 anything works but <root-domain>, or www.<root-domain>

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront

I've been suffering with these DNS settings for a while, and finally made a bit of progress.

I have a cloudfront distribution that points to an s3 bucket. Works properly when visiting the cloudfront dns.

The certificate is of course assigned, and alternative domain names to the cloudfront distribution.

My domain is on google domains, and made the name servers to route 53's

I made a route 53 hosted zone for the domain `<root-domain>`, and created alias records for `<root-domain>`, and `www.<root-domain>`. It doesn't work. Just for debugging I created another one for `asd.<root-domain>`, and that works.

Why?

Comment: If you give us the domain, this might be answerable.

Comment: fastifai.com is the domain

Comment: fastifai.com, www.fastifai.com, and asd.fastifai.com all work fine for me, with the same content and valid certificates. I suspect you're seeing cached records. Make sure you haven't overridden the domain in your computer's hosts file, too.

Comment: Interesting, it doesnt work for me, tried on 3 different devices, and different wifi as well

Comment: It all works fine for me too. Check for proxies or private DNS that may be throwing you off.